# Repeated note field in references when using ametsoc bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

The contents of the `note` field are shown two times in the bibliography. I do not know how to solve it. I am using `natbib`. The bibliography style is `ametsoc`.

```
@misc{Wikipedia2014Photodiode,
    Author = {Wikipedia},
    Howpublished = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode},
    Note = {[Online; accessed 25-June-2014]},
    Title = {Photodiode --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia},
    Year = {2014}}
```

This is the result:

> Wikipedia, 2014c: Photodiode — Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia. [Online; accessed 25-June-2014], http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode, [Online; accessed 25-June-2014].

I want the note field to appear only one time.

Below is the minimal code example you have asked me for.

Edit: Following the recommendations of Torbjørn T., I have removed the 'non-necessary' code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to give you a minimal working example that can be compiled. I have compiled it and the field note continues appearing twice.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{Wikipedia2014Photodiode,
    Author = {Wikipedia},
    Howpublished = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode},
    Note = {[Online; accessed 25-June-2014]},
    Title = {Photodiode --- {W}ikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
    Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ametsoc}

\begin{document}
\citep{Wikipedia2014Photodiode}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us some minimal compilable code which results in this problem. It is hard for us to reproduce your error. And we do not have any information about how you are treating your bib-stuff.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added the information you asked me for. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have to say though, that it is not *minimal*. And we can't compile it either, as we don't have all the files that are `\include`d. However, as this is just about the bibliography, I would guess that everything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` except for `\bibliography{bibliography}` can be removed? And `\cite{Wikipedia2014Photodiode}` added in of course.

Comment: I have followed Torbjørn T. suggestion and removed the non-necessary parts of the document to provide you with a compilable code.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code down to the bare bones minimum, i.e., to an MWE that generates the problem behavior you're looking to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turns out to be a bug in the function `misc` of the bibliography style file `ametsoc.bst`. (You would be correct in surmising that this function is in charge of typesetting entries of type `@misc`...) Specifically, the function contains the following line *twice*:

```
format.note output
```

Unsurprisingly, the doubling of this instruction causes the contents of the `note` field to be printed twice. The solution is to remove the first of the two lines with this directive. You could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `ametsoc.bst` in your file system. If you can't find it in your file system, you should be able to find a copy on the CTAN.
- Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `myametsoc.bst`. Do not edit an original file directly.
- Open the file `myametsoc.bst` in your favorite text editor. (If you don't have a favorite editor, the editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.)
- Search for the function named `misc`. In my copy of this file, this function starts on line 1320.
- In this function, locate the two lines that say

  ```
  format.note output
  ```
- Delete the *first* of these two lines, and leave the second untouched.
- Save the file `myametsoc.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update your TeX distribution's filename database appropriately.
- Start using the new style file by including the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{myametsoc}
  ```
- Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: You made my day Mico! The issue has been solved following your instructions. Thank you and all who have commented/answered my question.